# Python 3.2 script hang on third function

Tags: python, python-3.2

I am trying to make a very simple python script that pits two characters together, but while running the script, it executes the first two functions that the script uses to define the two characters stats, but when it gets to the third function, it just hangs.

Here's the code:

```
#STAPS: Strength Toughness Agility Perception weapon Skill
#A comparative simulator
import random
#Functions used to define character parameters
#Character 1's parameter function

def char1():
    global s1
    global t1
    global a1
    global p1
    global dam1
    global dt1
    global dr1
    global ac1
    global ws1
    s1 = int(input("Char1's Strength? "))
    t1 = int(input("Char1's Toughness? "))
    a1 = int(input("Char1's Agility? "))
    p1 = int(input("Char1's Perception? "))
    dam1 = int(input("Char1's Damage? "))
    dt1 = int(input("Char1's Damage Threshold? "))
    dr1 = int(input("Char1's Damage Resistance? "))
    ac1 = int(input("Char1's Armor Class? "))
    ws1 = int(input("Char1's Weapon Skill? "))

#Character 2's paramter function
def char2():
    global s2
    global t2
    global a2
    global p2
    global dam2
    global dt2
    global dr2
    global ac2
    global ws2
    s2 = int(input("Char2's Strength? "))
    t2 = int(input("Char2's Toughness? "))
    a2 = int(input("Char2's Agility? "))
    p2 = int(input("Char2's Perception? "))
    dam2 = int(input("Char2's Damage? "))
    dt2 = int(input("Char2's Damage Threshold? "))
    dr2 = int(input("Char2's Damage Resistance? "))
    ac2 = int(input("Char2's Armor Class? "))
    ws2 = int(input("Char2's Weapon Skill? "))

#Main battle function. Ordo Xenos calls this "complex and easy to misuse"
#Jury-rigged way of getting names, why did I include them anyways?

def stapsbatt(c1n,c2n,hp1,hp2):
    while hp1 > 0 or hp2 > 0:
    #determines original raw acc
        char1rawacc = ws1 - ac2
    #if statement settles it to minimum 95% acc
    if char1rawacc > 95:
        char1rawacc = 95
    #random int used to determine whether it's a hit or not
    char1hitnum = random.randint(0, 100)
    if char1rawacc > char1hitnum:
        moddam1 = dam1 - dt2
        if moddam1 < 0:
            moddam1 = 0
        rawdam1 = moddam1 * (100 - dr2)
        hp2 = hp2 - rawdam1
    #Now we move on to doing char2's batt calcs
    char2rawacc = ws2 - ac1
    if char2rawacc > 95:
        char2rawacc = 95
    char2hitnum = random.randint(0, 100)
    if char2rawacc > char2hitnum:
        moddam2 = dam2 - dt1
        if moddam2 < 0:
            moddam2 = 0
        rawdam2 = moddam2 * (100 - dr1)
        hp1 = hp1 - rawdam2
    if hp1 == 0:
        print(c2n, "has won!")
    else:
        print(c1n, "has won!")
    char1()
    char2()
    stapsbatt("Character 1", "Character 2",400,30)
    input("Press enter to exit. ")
```

And yes, this code is completely unedited, I realize my comments aren't very good.

Comment: @Klikun, don't abuse globals too much. There are better way to access variables from different scopes.

Comment: You say "yes, this code is completely unedited", so why not edit it? Add some print statement to work out where the code hangs and then post that (are fact that it is globals relevant etc.). [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example(]http://sscce.org/) :)

Comment: @Oz123 Sorry! I recently learned about functions, and have been meaning to transfer this simulation from pen and paper to script, so I jumped at the first chance I have. Still learning though, I just learned about scopes and very basic classes.

Comment: @hayden I already knew where the hang happened, I knew it was in the very beginning of the third function, I just didn't know what was causing it. What I meant by unedited is that I was hoping it was an excuse for my embarrassing comments.

Comment: "At the very beginning" was rather vague, print statements could have enabled you to hone in on the precise line (indeed CRTL+C stops the process and tells you the last run line) :)

Answer (score 1):

First, your comments must be at the same indentation level as the code.

Comment: Is that what could be causing it? I'll change it anyways, even if it isn't. EDIT: Okay, that wasn't what caused it.

Comment: also, at the time of writing this message, you don't seem to have any indentation inside function bodies either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're probably looking for:

```
while hp1 > 0 or hp2 > 0:
    #determines original raw acc
    char1rawacc = ws1 - ac2
```

This loop never ends, because whatever you do inside never changes its condition. Probably you wanted an `if`.

The rest: OMG. Seeing this code hurts. Let's make it a bit better.

Don't use `global` unless you have a damn good reason to do so. For now, consider this a matter of discipline; as you progress as a programmer you will see why separation of scopes matters.

Use functions to describe similar things *once*. It's the whole point: removing repeating parts, replacing them with names, with new 'words' that makes your language closer to the problem you're solving.

```
def get_character_description(name):
    print "Describe character %s" % name
    # input values here...
    return description

char1 = get_character_description('Liu Kang')
char2 = get_character_description('Sub Zero')
```

Use data structures. In this case, combine stats of a character into a single entity.

```
# Use a dict to describe character stats
def get_character_description(name):
    description = {}
    description['name'] = name
    print "Describe character %s" % name
    description['strength'] = int(input("%s's strength?"))
    # input other values here...
    return description

char1 = get_character_description('Pikachu')
if char1['strength'] > 100: ...
```

Consider creating a custom class to describe characters when you learn about classes:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def input(self):
        print "Let's define stats of %s" % self.name
        self.strength = int(input("Strength?"))
        # and so on

char1 = Character('J.C. Denton')
if char1.strength > 100: ...
```

After that, your code might look like this:

```
char1 = get_character_description('Liu Kang')
char2 = get_character_description('Sub Zero')
if char1.wins_over(char2):
   print char1.name, "has won"
else:
   print char2.name, "has won"
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the code, I realize it's extremely sloppy. I just got back into writing Python after about an 8 month break, and I was still a newbie when I stopped writing. I still only know the very basics of high-level programming, so I still know nothing about classes. I'm definitely going to commit these changes, as soon as I can understand them. Thanks for the constructive response.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code that are causing it to hang. I would suggest getting familiar with a python debugger, such as [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html). This will allow you to look at values during runtime, stepping through the program execution line-by-line.

Indentation issues aside, here are the problem areas I found:

1. In your while loop, you use `while hp1 > 0 and hp2 > 0` as your condition. You don't want to use `or` here, or it will keep looping until *both* chars have < 0 hp, so you should change it to `and`.
2. When calculating `rawacc` (for both chars), you used `if char1rawacc > 95`, which actually enforces a *maximum* on the `char1rawacc`. You did the same thing for `char2rawacc`. Switch these to `if char1rawacc < 95` and `if char2rawacc < 95`.
3. As a style note, if you are executing this as a script, you should put the function calls outside the function definitions themselves, a good way to do this is to put a block like this at the end of your script:

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        # the following only gets executed if the file is run as a script
        char1()
        char2()
        stapsbatt("Character 1", "Character 2", 400, 30)
```

Hopefully this gets you out of your infinite loop! I got the game working on my computer with these changes.

Now, as Oz123 mentions, you are really abusing global variables. Instead, you should look into creating and passing objects (see 9000's answer). For example, you could define a class for your character, and create two instances of this class (char1 and char2) that get passed to your battle function. This will also save you from a lot of redundant code. This will require some significant restructuring, but it will be worth it. If you run into problems with that, feel free to open a new question.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reply. I'm still pretty new to Python, and programming in general, so I've always got something more to learn. These fixes worked like a charm, and that "or" operator was a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Two immortal characters (with "or->and" fix) => infinite loop

```
moddam1 = dam1 - dt2
if moddam1 < 0:
    moddam1 = 0                  # dam1 <= dt2: moddam1 = 0
rawdam1 = moddam1 * (100 - dr2)  # rawdam1 == 0
hp2 = hp2 - rawdam1              # hp2 == const: immortality
```

Answer (score 0):

If it makes you feel better, it doesn't seem to be an issue with your program. (Nevermind yes it is, it's the while statement)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\staps.py", line 89, in <module>
    stapsbatt("Character 1", "Character 2",400,30)
  File "C:\Python32\staps.py", line 76, in stapsbatt
    char2hitnum = random.randint(0,100)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 215, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 191, in randrange
    return istart + self._randbelow(width)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 221, in _randbelow
    getrandbits = self.getrandbits
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It's hanging inside the random module, and despite trying several other functions (`random.randrage(0,100)`, and `random.choice(range(0,100))`) the problem still manifests. Oddly, there's no issues calling the functions outside your program.

Try cleaning up your code a bit and see if it improves. Generally, your globals should be declared at the beginning. Also, I think you mean to say "and" instead of "or" in this line: `while hp1 > 0 or hp2 > 0:`. Using an OR in this case means if char1 or char2 is alive. You only want to go until the fight is over (unless of course, you like beating a dead horse).